# List view Edit text row got cleared when moving from one row to another

Tags: android

I have  an xml with one textveiw and one edittext in it .I used this xml to get different rows in the list view of another xml file to list the data in that page.

The xml file that is used to list data in listview is as given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="2dip"
    android:paddingBottom="0dip">

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_Sort_Address"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    style="@style/ListTextViewStyle"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="No"
     android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <EditText 
    android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:inputType="number" 
    style="@style/EditTextStyle"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" 
    android:id="@+id/et_Sort_Order"
     android:layout_weight="1">

    </EditText>


      </LinearLayout>
```

I filled the Listview with data on another xml fils as given below

```
simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, alist,
                R.layout.sort_order_list_row, new String[] { "Sort_Address",
                        "Sort_FKDeliveryStatus", "Sort_PKDelivery",
                        "Sort_DeliveryOrder" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.tv_Sort_Address, R.id.tv_Sort_FKDeliveryStatus,
                        R.id.tv_Sort_PKDelivery, R.id.et_Sort_Order });
        listSortOrder.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

The problem with me is that if i have two row in the listview and when i 
placed a value in one of edit text row and move on to the another rows edit text the value placed in the first row got disappered.

```
 <ListView android:id="@+id/lv_Sort_Order"
       style="@style/ListTextBackGround"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"  
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1" 
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"      
     android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"     
     android:layout_marginRight="5dip" >
     </ListView>
```

to solve this I placed `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"` in the list view page to get focus on to the merged page. But it didn't solve the problem. Will anyone help me please.

Is there any property I need to be placed in the list view or in the merged Page?

Comment: @Arun...if you are playing with editText in ListView you have to use ViewHolder concept of Listview ....I will post a demo code

Comment: From where i can find the demo code

Comment: @ Arun...I have posted a demo code

Comment: @Arun...I have posted a new code of listview using viewholder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use this code :   

public class ListViewDemo extends Activity {

    private ListView listViewScore = null;
    private ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter = null;
    private String[] usernameArr = null;
    private String[] scoreArr = null;
    //ArrayList<String>  usernameArrLst = null ,scoreArrLst = null;
    //private Helper helper = null;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        listViewScore=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewScore);

        usernameArr = new String[]{"Alan","Bob","Carl","Doaniel","Evan","Fred","Gram"};
        scoreArr = new String[usernameArr.length];

        //usernameArrLst = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(usernameArr));
        //scoreArrLst = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(scoreArr));

        listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter();
        listViewScore.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
    }

    class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(usernameArr==null){
                return 0;
            }

            return usernameArr.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return usernameArr[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final ViewHolder viewHolder ;
            View rowView=view;

            if(rowView==null){
                LayoutInflater layoutinflate =LayoutInflater.from(ListViewDemo.this);
                rowView=layoutinflate.inflate(R.layout.listviewnewtext, parent, false);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.tv_Sort_Address = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Sort_Address);
                viewHolder.et_Sort_Order = (EditText)rowView.findViewById(R.id.et_Sort_Order);

                viewHolder.et_Sort_Order.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                            int after) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        scoreArr[viewHolder.ref] = s.toString();

                    }
                });

                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }else{
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            }

            viewHolder.ref = position;

            viewHolder.tv_Sort_Address.setText(usernameArr[position]);
            viewHolder.et_Sort_Order.setText(scoreArr[position]);

            return rowView;
        }

    }//class ends

    class ViewHolder{
        TextView tv_Sort_Address;
        EditText et_Sort_Order;
        int ref;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you use SimpleAdapter? Can you try using ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter.
Check [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listsactivity_layout) and any BaseAdapter example.

Comment: Thank for your comment.When i tried to extend the listview activity in my class,there occured navigation problem.because of that i extend activity in my class.So becuase of these reason i used Simple adapter for filling the listview.Frankly i am quite new in android because of that only i cant solve this problm

Comment: No issues Arun! Everybody was new to android once. Just in time you would improve. Welcome to the forum. IMHO Unless there is a reason you don't ve to extend Listview. The steps is simple find the listview id, create a array adapter and set adapter to the listview. Just read the link I've given right from top. You will understand everything.

Comment: Thanks santhosh.I will check in the way you have commeted.

Comment: How can we get data from the list view after fillin it in the list view?

Comment: listview.getAdapter().getItem(position) or make the list of items global and access the item using position.